# How should I correctly select entity from database?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am trying to add a new item into the database (with 1=>M relationship) and am stuck at selecting it in the method. How to connect this new contact to the existing account?

Method:

```
var contacts = _dataContext.Accounts.Select(a => a.Contacts.Where(c=>c.Email==email));

      
    var newContact = new Contact();
    
    newContact.FirstName = firstName;
    newContact.SecondName = secondName;
    newContact.Email = email;
    
        
    _dataContext.Contacts.Add(newContact);
    await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();`
```

Database structure:

```
public class Account
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string AccountName { get; set; }

  public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  public string SecondName { get; set; }

  public string Email { get; set; }

  public int AccountId { get; set; }

  public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to set the `AccountId` or `Account` property of the new `Contact`, or else add the `Contact` to the `Contacts` list of the appropriate `Account`.

Comment: Thank you for your responce @Eldar , this is exactly the problem, with my select expression I cant get the Account I want to add the new contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either set `AccountId` to the `Account.Id`'s value and add/update + save the new `Contact`, or you can simply add the `Contact` entity to the `Account`'s `Contacts` list and update + save it.

if you're simply trying to fetch a contact that has an email listed in one of their contact infos, for example 'abc@gmail.com' then you can do `_dataContext.Accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Contacts.Any(y => y.Email == "abc@gmail.com"))` I'm not sure that this is exactly what you want, but that'll do it, if you want the existing contacts as well as the main `Account` object, then you also need to remember to `.Include(x => x.Contacts)`, so that it'll be attached to the entity you fetch, and thus you can easily add a new contact to the list and save it, without having to manually attach stuff

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how should I select account from db correctly. When I am trying to add new Contact to List of contacts with the same email (var contacts = _dataContext.Accounts.Select(a => a.Contacts.Where(c=>c.Email==email));) in this way: (contacts.Add(newContact)) I got the mistake

Comment: if you're simply trying to fetch a contact that has an email listed in one of their contact infos, for example 'abc@gmail.com' then you can do `_dataContext.Accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Contacts.Any(y=>y.Email == "abc@gmail.com"))`

I'm not sure that this is exactly what you want, but that'll do it, if you want the existing contacts as well as the main `Account` object, then you also need to remember to `.Include(x=>x.Contacts)`, so that it'll be attached to the entity you fetch, and thus you can easily add a new contact to the list and save it, without having to manually attach stuff

Comment: @A Sad Shoe, please post your comment as an answer so I could accept it. I could just copy a comment and then post that as an answer myself, but that does not give you the credit